# C++ Using the increment operator on a pointer to dynamic memory

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, post-increment

Is it not valid to use an increment operator on a pointer to dynamic memory in C++ when assigning the values to said dynamic memory? Or am I doing something wrong here? I am unable to find anything definitive on this specific point in any of the forums in my web searches, (mostly here in stackoverflow).

This version of my function works perfectly:

```cpp
int* apply_all(const int* arr1 , size_t arr1_size, const int* arr2 , size_t arr2_size)
{
   int it {};
   int* pArr = new int[arr1_size * arr2_size];
   for(size_t i {}; i < arr1_size; ++i)
      for(size_t j {}; j < arr2_size; ++j)
         pArr[it++] = arr1[i]*arr2[j]; // <-- This works perfectly!
   return pArr;
}
```

The expected result of printing out the contents of the dynamic memory pointed to by the returned pointer is:

```
[ 10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60, 30, 60, 90, 40, 80, 120, 50, 100, 150 ]
```

But when I try the below version I get a seg fault:

```cpp
int* apply_all(const int* arr1 , size_t arr1_size, const int* arr2 , size_t arr2_size)
{
   int* pArr = new int[arr1_size * arr2_size];
   for(size_t i {}; i < arr1_size; ++i)
      for(size_t j {}; j < arr2_size; ++j)
         *(pArr++) = arr1[i]*arr2[j]; // <-- This does not work!!
   return pArr;
}
```

The above causes this output:

```
"[ 0, 0, 0, 1041, 0, 741351515, 539766816, 824192048, 741422128, 539766816, 858862647, 825569589, 891300917, 909588787, 909195318 ]

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B)   execution time : 0.114 s"
```

This is from an assignment in a beginning C++ course where one of the requirements is to write a function with 2 int arrays and their sizes as the parameters. The function is to return a pointer to an array in dynamic memory (composed of values arithmetically generated using the input parameters). I am using codeblocks in linux mint with GNU GCC Compiler (c++ compiler: G++) and GDB. But I have no compiler flags for C++ selected as they were causing problems when selected and I read somewhere ( I believe it was a post on here ) to fix the problem by not selecting any flag. (Not sure if this is a factor or not.)

I have also tried *pArr++ and get the same result. Is this something with C++ or is it because of my compiler or something. I have not been studying C++ for very long and only started studying coding with C in October of last year, so there is much I still do not know that may be basic to you all. But I REALLY want to learn. Thanks in advance. If you need the entire program let me know. I just surmised it wasn't really pertinent to the question.

Comment: when you return the second version your pArr points at the end instead of the beginning since you had been incrementing it all that time.  I believe what you seek is to return pArr - arr1_size * arr2_size, or maybe just store a copy to return before you go incrementing it.

Comment: That's a rather meandering introduction to your question. The question would probably be better received if it started with the actual problem (as focused and abstract as feasible), then moved on to your hypothesis regarding why your code failed, and (if necessary) end with the assignment that led you to this code.

Comment: @Abel Thanks big brother! (genesis reference). You got it man! wow, that was right in front of me :O . Thank you so much. I went with using a variable to save the original position and that worked like a charm. So uh. How do I close this? This is my first question I ever asked here.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you I will take that into consideration. That is why I asked my question at the beginning and then meandered as I did not know how to say what the problem was other than why does this fail. Plus the instructions here say to give a lot of details. Hard to get the right balance but your input helps.

Comment: @JaMiT . Does it look better now?

Comment: @SethVan It looks better, but you are still starting with your hypothesis instead of your issue. Would you have been satisfied with the answer *"It is valid to use an increment operator on a pointer to dynamic memory when assigning the values to said dynamic memory, as long as you stay within the allocation"*? I doubt it. Your real question is (was) why you got garbage values followed by a segmentation fault when incrementing a pointer instead of incrementing an index. That is what you should have used to attract the right people to answer. There is a place for hypotheses; it's not the start.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you. I understand what you are saying. I just don't know how to word it. Are you suggesting something like "Why am I getting garbage values followed by a segmentation fault when incrementing a pointer instead of incrementing an index?"?

Comment: @SethVan That could work as the lead-in. There's probably no need to edit this question since you got an acceptable answer, but keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you increment a pointer you have to save a copy before you return it, this is also an advice for Linked List where you access each following nodes but want to save address of the very first one. So in your case:

```cpp
int* apply_all(const int* arr1 , size_t arr1_size, const int* arr2 , size_t arr2_size)
{
   int* pArr = new int[arr1_size * arr2_size];
   Int* tmp = pArr; // you store pointer of pArr in tmp, it will not be incremented.
   for(size_t i {}; i < arr1_size; ++i)
      for(size_t j {}; j < arr2_size; ++j)
         *(pArr++) = arr1[i]*arr2[j]; // <-- This does not work!!
   return tmp; // you return tmp which point at the address of pArr where the first item is located
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I realize now that that is probably something I should have already known. But to be honest, I have always just used array notation like pArr[i] in the past and only just now wanted to try an incrementor on the pointer because I wanted to be like the cool kids :) as I have seen a lot of concise and neat looking code once in a while online with that kind of notation. And when you bring up linked lists that makes a lot of sense.